# Atualizando grande quantidade de dados no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela `MyISAM` com mais de 200 mil registros.

De tempos em tempos preciso fazer uma atualização geral no conteúdo.
Crio uma nova tabela e importo TODOS lançamentos para a tabela 'segunda' no `phpMyAdmin`.
Até aí tudo bem.
Depois disso rodo um script que renomeia as tabelas:

```
$sql = "RENAME TABLE primeira TO outra,segunda TO primeira;";
```

É aí que está o problema, algumas vezes trava tudo e é preciso reiniciar o `MySql`.

Pensei em usar o `alter table`, mas tá me parecendo que é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Qual seria a atualização geral que você precisa fazer? Talvez a melhor abordagem seja estudar a sua necessidade e procurar uma alternativa. Não é normal ter que atualizar 200 mil registros de uma só vez

Comment: Uma série de coisas, desde corrigir erros de ortografia até criar novas correspondências, fazer isso online seria muito demorado. Meu problema está no rename.

Comment: Corrigir erros de ortografia você pode fazer usando uma trigger com uma função, por exemplo. Que tipo de correspondência? Você pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: A nível de usuários, os dados são somente para leitura. Diariamente agrego cerca de 200 lançamentos. Mas, a cada 4 meses eu preciso fazer uma alteração geral. Alterar campos, coisas assim. Dividir uma classificação de cor em outras duas ou três...

Comment: Eu ainda acho a melhor forma seria estudar um jeito de não precisar mudar tantos dados de uma vez, mas como alternativa você pode criar uma `view`, jogar para outra tabela os dados, alterar o que quer alterar, ou jogar já alterando e muda apenas na `view` o nome da tabela de referência

Comment: Agradeço Sorack, vou pesquisar. Alguém me ajuda com a questão do rename' ?

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estratégia seria estudar exatamente as alterações nos dados que você realiza para sejam otimizadas sem a necessidade de alterar 200 mil registros ao mesmo tempo. Porém com as informações que foram fornecidas, talvez a melhor abordagem seja criar uma [`view`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html), transpor os dados para a outra tabela com as alterações necessárias e alterar na `view` a tabela base. Assim você pode consultar os dados na `view` sem maiores problemas;

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_tabela;
CREATE VIEW view_tabela AS SELECT * FROM tabela_1;

... insere e atualiza na tabela_2

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_tabela;
CREATE VIEW view_tabela AS SELECT * FROM tabela_2;
```

Comment: Opa ... vou estudar isso... obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Acredito que possa solucionar este problema, da seguinte forma.
1 - Criar nova tabela
2 - Importar os dados da Tabela 1 (antiga) para a Tabela recém criada
`INSERT INTO TABELA2 (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ...)
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2,... FROM TABELA1 ;`

Espero ter ajudado em alguma coisa.

Att,

:)

Comment: Ajuda sim, obrigado. A questão é que são muitas mudanças na nova tabela. Eu teria duas opções: 1 - apagar a tabela1 antes de 'puxar' os dados da tabela2 .... os usuários vão ver uma base de dados vazia por alguns minutos, ou, 2 - mudar o nome das tabelas......

Comment: Neste caso, acredito que seria viável criar a nova tabela (mesma estrutura da antiga), transferir os dados para ela. Logo após, realiza o Truncate da tabela (limpa os registros e deixa o contador da forenkey como 1) e depois realiza as modificações. Mas antes de realizar em produção, faça uma simulação em uma ambiente de testes ou em outro banco de dados de teste do MySQL. Acredito que resolva :)